# how to change is background color of selected item in list in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

only selected item have change the background color of list,
please help to how to change the background color of specific element in this list items

```
 <div style={{ padding: '0px 28px', marginBottom: '20px' }}>
               <div className='date__container'>
                  {arrdays.map((dayy, id) => (
                     <TimeContainer
                        day={dayy.day}
                        date={dayy.date}
                       
                     />
                  ))}
               </div>
            </div>
```

TimeContainer component

```
const TimeContainer = (props) => {
      const month = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'];

      
      return (
         <div
            className='dateBox'
           
            style={{
               backgroundColor: `${props.isSelected===props.key ? 'purple' : 'white'}`,
            }}
         >
            <p style={{ fontSize: '16px', color: '#888', fontWeight: 'bold' }}>
               {props.day}
            </p>
            <p style={{ color: 'black', fontSize: '17px', fontWeight: 'bold' }}>
               {props.date}
            </p>
         </div>
      );
   };
```

Comment: Instead of ${props.isSelected===props.key ? 'purple' : 'white'}
You can try
${props.isSelected ? 'purple' : 'white'}
Note : Check if isSelected is boolean

Comment: Please share your event-handler - specifically, the handler which is triggered when user 'selects' an item.

Comment: Try something like this: `<TimeContainer day={dayy.day} date={dayy.date} key={id} isSelected={selectedId} setSelectedKey={setSelectedId} />` and declare `const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = React.useState(-1);`. And within `TimeContainer` when user selects, make sure to invoke `props.setSelectedKey(props.key);` .